# ArcGIS Desktop 10.4: Identify results

Tags: arcgis-desktop, identify

I have already created several file geodatabases, sometimes with large feature classes.
Identifying features on one of these feature classes takes lots of time, showing polygons that are even not on the screen.
An identify on an other large feature class (also an other filegeodatabase) but within the same session shows the data for just one polygon?

Selection option within the session: tolerance of 3 pixels

Spatal index is up-to-date for both file geodatabases. Attribute index has been created for the field used for symbology.

Are there some other factors explaining this different behaviour?

Comment: The question is why the command shows the info of such a large number of polygons, even the attribute data for polygons not on the screen(data view).

Comment: You need to add way more information, edit your question to include: number of features and fields, are they multipart, what is your data (e.g. polygons of house so discrete entities or geology a continuous coverage)? Are geometries overlapping or tesselate? Where is your data stored, c, network, Dropbox etc?

Comment: I receive the info for a lots of polygons even not on the screen.

Comment: One feature class: houses
Other one: info about vegetation
I see the info for buildings, even not on the screen. I click on the middle of a house. I receive attribute data for just one vegetation polygon. I click on the vegetation polygon, near the same house. No multipart polygons, neither for houses, neither for vegetation. Data is stored on the same file server. I am working remotely. Databases have not been created on the same moment.

Comment: Edit your question, don't stick extra vital  information in your comments. People come to help you should not be forced to extract additional information from your comments.